# Why doesn't mean square error work in case of angular data?

Tags: python, neural-network, radians, mean-square-error

Suppose, the following is a dataset for solving a regression problem:

```
H   -9.118   5.488   5.166   4.852   5.164   4.943   8.103  -9.152  7.470  6.452  6.069  6.197  6.434  8.264  9.047         2.222
H    5.488   5.166   4.852   5.164   4.943   8.103  -9.152  -8.536  6.452  6.069  6.197  6.434  8.264  9.047 11.954         2.416 
C    5.166   4.852   5.164   4.943   8.103  -9.152  -8.536   5.433  6.069  6.197  6.434  8.264  9.047 11.954  6.703         3.028
C    4.852   5.164   4.943   8.103  -9.152  -8.536   5.433   4.924  6.197  6.434  8.264  9.047 11.954  6.703  6.407        -1.235
C    5.164   4.943   8.103  -9.152  -8.536   5.433   4.924   5.007  6.434  8.264  9.047 11.954  6.703  6.407  6.088        -0.953 
H    4.943   8.103  -9.152  -8.536   5.433   4.924   5.007   5.057  8.264  9.047 11.954  6.703  6.407  6.088  6.410         2.233
H    8.103  -9.152  -8.536   5.433   4.924   5.007   5.057   5.026  9.047 11.954  6.703  6.407  6.088  6.410  6.206         2.313
H   -9.152  -8.536   5.433   4.924   5.007   5.057   5.026   5.154 11.954  6.703  6.407  6.088  6.410  6.206  6.000         2.314
H   -8.536   5.433   4.924   5.007   5.057   5.026   5.154   5.173  6.703  6.407  6.088  6.410  6.206  6.000  6.102         2.244 
H    5.433   4.924   5.007   5.057   5.026   5.154   5.173   5.279  6.407  6.088  6.410  6.206  6.000  6.102  6.195         2.109
```

the left-most column is the class data. The rest of the features are all angular data.

My initial setup for the model was as follows:

```
def create_model(n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2, num_features):
    # create the model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(num_features,)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden_1, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden_2, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

    # instantiate the optimizer
    opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)

    # compile the model
    model.compile(
         loss="mean_squared_error",
         optimizer=opt,
         metrics=["mean_squared_error"]
    )

    # return model
    return model
```

This model didn't produce the correct outcome.

Someone told me that MSE doesn't work in the case of angular data. So, I need to use a custom output layer and a custom error function.

Why doesn't mean square error work in the case of angular data?

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: if the data may not be normally distributed, maybe try a transformation: http://www.biostathandbook.com/transformation.html

Comment: From your data interpretation, I think you are doing logistic regression. Why do you use the loss function of linear regression? Can you explain your data? Which column is the target y?

Comment: @lazy, *Why do you use the loss function of linear regression?* --- Coz, I don't know what to use. *Which column is the target y?* --- the right-most column.

Comment: Looking at your data -- is that the complete set? Because it looks like you have 15 independent variables and just 10 data points. Also, your example code does not show how you're feeding your data to the modelling process

Comment: If the features are all angular -- am I correct to assume that they're given in radians? If yes, is it relevant how many "revolutions" they entail? Some of them seem to be several full circles before or behind some others, but you don't state if you want your model to include that information or not.

Answer (score 2):

Data that represent angles like 180 degrees, causes problems with most loss functions because they are not meant for radiants. MSE calculates a huge error between 0 and 359 although 0=360. It simply doesn’t understand the concepts of radiants and angles.

There are a number of ways to fix this depending on what you want to predict. The easiest would be to transform your data via sinus function and then use the transformed data for training. You would need to apply the inverse function to your predictions.

The other option is to customise the MSE loss function to transform x via the sinus function.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by "angular" you mean some form of representation of an **angle**. If this is the case, then MSE does not work well because it does not have a concept of 0 == 360 (or equivalent regularities in radians), thus e.g. predicting 359.999999 for a correct label of 0 will create a huge error, while it should produce a tiny error.

Comment: so, what is the solution, then?

Comment: A custom loss function, e.g. squared sine between the angles.

Comment: Yet the sample values shown in the question are around the -10º to +10º span, so the model shouldn't need to care about 360 = 0. Are you cutting more extreme values @user366312 ? If so, is the data about a revolving phenomena? If so, could you acquire the cumulative angle data accounting former revolutions and work with that? (370, 700, 1088, etc instead of 10, -20, 8, etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
%matplotlib inline

def create_model(n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2, num_features):
    # create the model
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(num_features,)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden_1, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden_2, activation='sigmoid')) # relu ignores data information, so we choose sigmoid.
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

    # instantiate the optimizer
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)

    # compile the model
    model.compile(
         loss="mean_squared_error",
         optimizer="adam",
#          metrics=["mean_squared_error"]
    )

    # return model
    return model

ss = [['H',-9.118,5.488,5.166,4.852,5.164,4.943,8.103,-9.152,7.470,6.452,6.069,6.197,6.434,8.264,9.047, 2.222],
['H',5.488,5.166,4.852,5.164,4.943,8.103,-9.152,-8.536,6.452,6.069,6.197,6.434,8.264,9.047,11.954, 2.416],
['C',5.166,4.852,5.164,4.943,8.103,-9.152,-8.536,5.433,6.069,6.197,6.434,8.264,9.047,11.954,6.703, 3.028],
['C',4.852,5.164,4.943,8.103,-9.152,-8.536,5.433,4.924,6.197,6.434,8.264,9.047,11.954,6.703,6.407,-1.235],
['C',5.164,4.943,8.103,-9.152,-8.536,5.433,4.924,5.007,6.434,8.264,9.047,11.954,6.703,6.407,6.088,-0.953],
['H',4.943,8.103,-9.152,-8.536,5.433,4.924,5.007,5.057,8.264,9.047,11.954,6.703,6.407,6.088,6.410, 2.233],
['H',8.103,-9.152,-8.536,5.433,4.924,5.007,5.057,5.026,9.047,11.954,6.703,6.407,6.088,6.410,6.206, 2.313],
['H',-9.152,-8.536,5.433,4.924,5.007,5.057,5.026,5.154,11.954,6.703,6.407,6.088,6.410,6.206,6.000, 2.314],
['H',-8.536,5.433,4.924,5.007,5.057,5.026,5.154,5.173,6.703,6.407,6.088,6.410,6.206,6.000,6.102, 2.244],
['H',5.433,4.924,5.007,5.057,5.026,5.154,5.173,5.279,6.407,6.088,6.410,6.206,6.000,6.102,6.195, 2.109]]

data = pd.DataFrame(ss)
y =data.iloc[:,-1:]
x = data.iloc[:,1:-1]

# scaler, Accelerating model convergence
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
x_model = scaler.fit(x)
x = scaler.transform(x)

y_model = scaler.fit(y)
y = scaler.transform(y)

# model 
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
model = create_model(n_hidden_1=4, n_hidden_2=2, num_features=15)

model.fit(x,y,epochs=1000)

# predict 
y_pre = model.predict(x)
print('predict: ',y_model.inverse_transform(y_pre))
print('y: ',y_model.inverse_transform(y))
predict:  [[ 2.2238724 ]
 [ 2.415551  ]
 [ 3.0212667 ]
 [-1.1861311 ]
 [-0.98702306]
 [ 2.2277246 ]
 [ 2.3132346 ]
 [ 2.3148017 ]
 [ 2.235104  ]
 [ 2.1206288 ]]
y:  [[ 2.222]
 [ 2.416]
 [ 3.028]
 [-1.235]
 [-0.953]
 [ 2.233]
 [ 2.313]
 [ 2.314]
 [ 2.244]
 [ 2.109]]
```

I wrote a piece of code and annotated it. In terms of the results, the difference is very small. Friendly tip: pay attention to the over fitting of the model.

Comment: Just tell me what you have done different than the original model?

Comment: I just changed the activation function of the hidden layer. The `relu` function will ignore some information, so I replaced it with the `sigmoid` function. If you don't understand the characteristics of these two functions, you can check their function images.

Comment: 1. `data scaler`, Accelerating model convergence. 
2. `relu` ignores data information, so we choose `sigmoid`.